# Browser Not Being Launched From Service

Tags: android

I am trying to launch a browser from within my service class but it doesn't work. Below is sample code from my service class's onStartCommand method:

```
    Toast.makeText(context, "Service called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(context, null, null, 1);
    final Context cont = context;

    String expectedPattern = "MMM d, yyyy";
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedPattern);

    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(cont, "In service handler", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dbContacts = dbHandler.getAllContacts();
                for(Contact cn : dbContacts) {
                    Toast.makeText(cont, "Checking contacts...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String url = "http://www.example.com/send_sms?from=123456789&to=";
                    final String phone = cn.getContactphone();
                    String dob = cn.getContactdob();
                    dobDate = sdf.parse(dob);
                    today = new Date();
                    long diffInMs = today.getTime() - dobDate.getTime();
                    int diff = (int) diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
                    Toast.makeText(cont, "Diff is " + diff, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if(diff == 0) {
                        String smsBody = "Welcome message";

                        String SMS_SENT = "SMS_SENT";
                        String SMS_DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

                        PendingIntent sentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0);
                        PendingIntent deliveredPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont, 0, new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);

                        // When SMS has been sent
                        cont.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceive(Context cont, Intent intent) {
                                switch (getResultCode()) {
                                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                        Toast.makeText(cont, "SMS sent successfully to " + phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;

                                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                        Toast.makeText(cont, "Generic failure cause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                                        Toast.makeText(cont, "Service is currently unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                        Toast.makeText(cont, "No pdu provided", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                        Toast.makeText(cont, "Radio was explicitly turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }, new IntentFilter(SMS_SENT));

                        // When SMS has been delivered
                        cont.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceive(Context cont, Intent intent) {
                                switch (getResultCode()) {
                                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                        Toast.makeText(cont, "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                        Toast.makeText(cont, "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }, new IntentFilter(SMS_DELIVERED));

                        // Get default instance of SmsManager
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                        // Send a text-based SMS
                        Toast.makeText(cont, "About to launch browser", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        url += phone + "&msg=" + smsBody;
                        Toast.makeText(cont, "URL is " + url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
                        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                        startActivity(launchBrowser);
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };

    Thread stephThread = new Thread(r);
    stephThread.start();

    stopSelf();

    return START_STICKY;
```

It works fine up to the last Toast displaying the correct URL, but it doesn't launch the browser.

How can I correct this please? And how can I make the interaction with the browser to be in the background, that is, the url is called but the browser doesn't doesn't pop up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293549/5798690).
I needed to use an AsyncTask after compiling the required apache configurations as shown below (in the doInBackground() method):

```
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[i]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                InputStream it = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(it);
                BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(read);
                StringBuilder dta = new StringBuilder();
                String chunks ;
                while((chunks = buff.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    dta.append(chunks);
                }
            }
            else {
                //Do else here
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```